# Extend GoogleSheets Cell Formula to New Row in Column

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to extend a column formula automatically to new rows when they are added.

My formula is =IF(C:C < TODAY(), 1, 0).

Thanks,
Beth

I know if I use Arrayformula it should work, but I keep getting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=BYROW(C2:C, LAMBDA(cx,if(cx="",,if(cx<today(),1,0))))
```

alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),IF(C2:C<TODAY(),1,0),))
```

[image]